# Appium/Selenium TestNG Gradle DexArchiveBulderException Build Errors

Tags: selenium, gradle, build, testng, appium

I am an intermediate level tester who is currently exploring options for mobile automation. I am familiar with Appium/Selenium and am now attempting to introduce TestNG to manage test suites.

I have run into an error when attempting to build a simple project to begin mobile testing using TestNG and Appium/Selenium. I am unable to figure out how to fix this error.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mikejohnson.testngtest"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9' // added this to resolve initial build conflict
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'org.testng:testng:6.11' //added this
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.7.1' //added this
    implementation 'io.appium:java-client:5.0.4' //added this
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:assembleDebug]
Warning:Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\Mike.Johnson\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\3.7.1\460c39abe149b7c649dd05dd71ab64ca80f738aa\selenium-firefox-driver-3.7.1.jar
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxBinary.class
Error:com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\Mike.Johnson\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.seleniumhq.selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\3.7.1\460c39abe149b7c649dd05dd71ab64ca80f738aa\selenium-firefox-driver-3.7.1.jar
Information:BUILD FAILED in 10s
Information:4 errors
Information:1 warning
Information:See complete output in console
```

To get to this point all I have done is create a basic android project and attempted to add the required dependencies for TestNG and Appium/Selenium to build.gradle

The errors are introduced when combining the dependencies for TestNG and Appium/Selenium. The project is able to successfully build with just TestNG dependencies, or just Appium/Selenium dependencies. As soon as I combine TestNG along with Appium/Selenium, errors begin to appear.

I have searched and tried many possible solutions, however it always ends with a DexArchiveBulderException. I  do not have the experience to deduce what is going wrong with the dependencies, and there is very little information available on 'DexArchiveBuilderException' when searching.

If there is any other information I can provide, please let me know. Thank you for the assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The initial problem is that you are trying to create Selenium tests inside Android project, at least it looks like you are adding dependencies to `build.gradle` in Android project.

And that is really strange way to start. Take look at official [Appium java-client tests](https://github.com/appium/java-client/tree/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client) to get understanding how to design project

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific; I am preparing to do mobile automation using appium. I am already familiar with Selenium.

Comment: I updated answer. You need to create separate project and run tests on PC/VM with appropriate configuration (JVM, Android SDK, etc.)

Comment: I am already familiar with appium and have it set up to run tests using Android SDK, etc. I am using Android Studio. This doesn't help me. I need help figuring out why TestNG dependencies conflict with Appium/Selenium, and how to fix. Thanks

Comment: Once again: Don't create appium tests in Android studio and more over - part of Android project. It won't work. The conflict you are facing is that you are trying to build automation testing project inside Android project and mixing dependencies, but it doesn't work this way. If you create simple java project and add just appium & testng dependencies it will work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed - recreated project in Intellij IDEA as a basic gradle/java project.